# Переключение классов css

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код

```
$(".main-nav a").click(function() {                 
        var scrollId = $(this).attr("href");  
        change_active($(this), scrollId);                 
        scroll_if_anchor(scrollId);               
        return false;
      });
    function change_active(href, scrollId) {
      console.log(href);
        href
          .removeClass("active")
          .filter("[href=" + scrollId +"]").addClass("active");            
    }
```

Класс устанавливается, но не удаляется с предыдущего элемента - a, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому-что в this - один конкретный элемент а не предыдущий селектор.

вот это вы наверное хотели:

```
var href=$(".main-nav a");
href.click(function () {
    var scrollId = $(this).attr("href");
    change_active($(this));
    //scroll_if_anchor(scrollId);
    return false;
});

function change_active(current) {
    console.log(href);
    href.removeClass("active");
    current.addClass("active");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/P3c89/